# Doesn't show arrows in input type number on Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: jquery, css, html, ruby-on-rails-5

I don't see arrows in input type number on Microsoft Edge browser.
I do see them in Chrome and FireFox. I'm using Ruby On Rails framework. 
Please help me find a solution

Comment: It's not your fault. Edge have a bug, you can even type anything inside number type input.   Check this https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/110895/

Comment: So is there a way to fix it? because i want that arrows in edge

Comment: You can use a polyfill like in this github link [https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill](https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's generally very little you can do when browsers don't support stuff you want. You can try to implement polyfills (as already suggested), but that's cumbersome and introduces a lot of code for solving a corner case. Depending on the business value of the feature, I would simply accept they won't be there and move on.